# Hibernate updating one to many collection when object removed from collection

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have run into a nasty bug with jpa and hibernate.  I have a billing class with the following annotation:

```
@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name="ch1_id", referencedColumnName="id")
private List<BillingItem>billingItems = new ArrayList<BillingItem>();
```

Now I need to filter deleted items from the collection but cannot use anything but jpa.  No hibernate specific annotations allowed.  So I wrote a post load function:

```
@PostLoad
public void postLoad() {
    ArrayList<BillingItem>tempItems = new ArrayList<BillingItem>();

    Iterator<BillingItem> i = this.billingItems.iterator();
    BillingItem item;
    while(i.hasNext()) {
        item = i.next();            
        if( item.getStatus().equals("D")) {
            tempItems.add(item);                
        }                       
    }

    this.billingItems.removeAll(tempItems);
}
```

However when there are deleted items to filter I'm seeing

Hibernate: update billing_on_item set ch1_id=null where ch1_id=? and id=?

which produces an exception because ch1_id is a foreign key and cannot be null.  However hibernate is binding the parameters to correct values.  Why is this update occurring in the first place?  How do I correct the error?

Thanks in advance,

Randy

Answer (score 4):

By removing the items from the collection, you're telling Hibernate that the association between the two entities doesn't exist anymore, so obviously, Hibernate removes what materializes this association in the database: it sets the foreign key to null.

What you probably want is just a getter in your entity that returns only the non-deleted items:

```
public List<BillingItem> getNonDeletedItems() {
    List<BillingItem> result = new ArrayList<BillingItem>();
    for (BillingItem item : this.billingItems) {
        if (!"D".equals(item.getStatus()) {
            result.add(item);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Thanks man!  I never even thought of a simple elegant solution such as this.  Makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

The `@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)` line says that it will cascade ALL updates. Look into [CascadeType](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/CascadeType.html).